# Error 500 al subir mi proyecto en Laravel a servidor compartido

Tags: laravel

Realice un proyecto con Laravel 5.6 y estoy intentando subirlo a un servidor compartido (000webhost.com), pero no entiendo por que me da error 500, mi versión de PHP es 7.1, y la carpeta `storage` y  todas las carpetas tienen permisos 777. Alguien me puede ayudar?

La estructura de la carpatas del servidor es asi

```
- public_html
  - * mis archivos de laravel (solo lo que estaba en la carpeta public) *
- tmp
- * mis archivos de laravel  (todos excepto la carpeta public) *
```

Ayuda, por favor

este es mi ultimo registro en mi log de laravel

```
[2018-07-18 13:06:24] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(885): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(813): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(780): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(721): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(215): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#15 /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/public_html/index.php(50): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#16 {main}
"}
```

> No puedo correr SSH, es decir, no puedo ejecutar comandos, el hosting no lo permite

Comment: Es extraño, todo dependerá de la estructura, ¿en que archivo cambiaste la redirección de public a public_html?, no creo que sea de mod_rewrite, pero igual si puedes verifica que esté habilitado.

Comment: todas las carpetas no tienen que tener permiso 777, solamente Storage y las de public, con esas son suficiente.

Comment: si, el mod rewrite esta habilitado... y puse las rutas relativas del servidor compartido hacia los archivos para que no hubieran errores

Comment: las rutas absolutas, disculpa

Comment: production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /storage/ssd3/828/6440828/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42) en el archivo .env ya tienes APP_KEY????

Comment: si, ya lo resolvi. El problema es que al parecer el servidor no estaba leyendo el archivo .env, por lo que procedi a colocar los valores directamente en los archivos de configuracion de laravel

Answer (score 0):

Creo que viene por un tema de Cache de laravel.

Ya que no podes correr comando desde SSH probaria a ver si funciona lo siguiente:

**1.Creas una ruta cualquiera y haces que esa ruta llame al comando**

```
Route::get('/configurar-cache', function() {
    //probaria esto primero
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    //si no funciona el anterior probaria este
    //$exitCode = Artisan::call('key:generate');
});
```

**2.llamas a esa ruta desde el browser para que se ejecute el comando.**

```
http://tudominio/configurar-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Actualizaste los archivos correspondientes para asegurarte de enlazar la carpeta public con el resto de archivos de Laravel?

Debes modificar el archivo index.php que esta dentro de public y que en éste momento debe estar dentro de public_html en tu host, quedando de una manera similar a lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Ademas debes asegurarte de tener los permisos correctos en /storage

> fuente: [The simple guide to deploy Laravel 5 application on shared hosting](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)